# não consigo instalar o: pip install cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pip

```
Collecting cx_Freeze
  Using cached cx_Freeze-6.13.1.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ?─> [57 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=59.0.1
        Using cached setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel>=0.36.2
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting cx-logging>=3.0
        Using cached cx_Logging-3.0.tar.gz (26 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: cx-logging
        Building wheel for cx-logging (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for cx-logging (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [7 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_ext
        creating build
        creating build\implib.win-amd64-3.1
        building 'cx_Logging' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for cx-logging
        Running setup.py clean for cx-logging
      Failed to build cx-logging
      Installing collected packages: cx-logging, wheel, setuptools
        Running setup.py install for cx-logging: started
        Running setup.py install for cx-logging: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Running setup.py install for cx-logging did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [7 lines of output]
        running install
        C:\Users\Windows.lite\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        running build
        running build_ext
        building 'cx_Logging' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
     
      Encountered error while trying to install package.
     
      cx-logging
     
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
?─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Esse é o erro que eu estou sofrendo, alguém consegue saber o por que disso?

Comment: A mensagem diz *This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely **not a problem with pip**. Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/*

Answer (score -1):

Basta você instalar: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!